# Function giving a None value when it should output an integer

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm writing a simple 'guess the number' game and wants the program to check if the input given is an integer before proceeding to compare it with the generated number. Here's the code:

```
import random

def guessFunc():
    try:
        guess1 = int(input())
        return guess1
    except ValueError:
        print('Input an integer!')
        guessFunc()

secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)
for guessTaken in range(1,7):
    print('Guess a number. You have ' + str(7 - guessTaken) + ' guesses left.')

    guess = guessFunc()

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Too low')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Too high')
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('You got it! You took ' + str(guessTaken) + ' guesses.')
else:
    print('The number is ' + str(secretNumber))
```

When I test the program, if I always input an integer, the program runs as expected. If I input anything else (a string for instance), it sends a message asking for an integer, which is also expected. But if I then input an integer, the program causes an error as follow:

> if guess < secretNumber:
>
> TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()

I don't understand why the function is outputting a None value. It only happens when I first input a string followed by an integer.

Separately, is there a cleaner/neater way to write the code to check whether the input is an integer in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'recursive' call in line 9 `guessFunc()` is not being returned, it's just being called. If you change that to `return guessFunc()` it works.

With regards to your question about checking for integers, your way is actually a very Pythonic way of doing it. Instead of checking whether or not the input is an integer, which would take time always, you assume it's an integer and handle the exception when something goes wrong, which takes time only when something goes wrong.

Comment: Referring to my original code, can you please explain the flow of the function if I initially input a string such as "hello"? I guess it's never stored in a variable (guess1)? It then calls the function again, and if I input an integer, it should be stored this time, and returns the integer? I don't quite understand why a None value is returned..

Comment: Thanks @RolfofSaxony, I wanted to accept it right away but the system only let me do so after a certain period of time. Just accepted the answer :)

Comment: @Let'sCode A function returns ''None' by default >>> def abc():
...  pass
... 
>>> print abc()
None

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, but the first part of the function does have 'return guess1'. My logic was: input string > call function again > input integer > return guess1 (which is an integer). Please correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: It's calling the guessFunc again 'inside' the guessFunc call. So even though the call inside the call is returning an integer, the 'outer' function call is executing line 9, which does nothing with the return value for the inner call

Comment: @JorickSpitzen, got you. Thanks a lot!